# How to avoid " " in select statement in column name for column that has numberAlphabet pattern in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, create-table

I have doubts regarding double quote column name in Oracle. I tried creating column name in number_alphabets pattern but this won't work. Then I used double quote and I was able to create table with this column name. When I do select, column name comes within double quote.
I have attached script in here.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(       
  "100_title"     VARCHAR2(200) NULL  
)     
            
SELECT * FROM test
```

When I do select, in result set, column name will be "100_title" but I do not want "" in it. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) documentation:

> 2. Nonquoted identifiers cannot be Oracle Database reserved words. Quoted identifiers can be reserved words, although this is not recommended.

and

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.
> 7. Nonquoted identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters from your
>    database character set and the underscore (_). Database links can contain
>    periods (.) and "at" signs (@).
>
>    Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well
>    as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain
>    double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

So your question:

> When I do select, in result set, column name will be "100_title" but I do not want "" in it. Is there a way to fix this?

The column identifier `100_title` starts with a non-alphabetic character so by point 6 of that documentation you must use double quotes with the identifier.

How the column name displays depends on the user interface you are using. On [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28c16709aab07cb2b5edf3cec0727424), the column name is displayed without quotes and this will be the same with many other interfaces.

If the user interface you are using only outputs the identifier with surrounding quotes then you could change the identifier from `"100_title"` to `title_100` as this starts with an alphabetic character and contains only alpha-numeric and underscore characters and, thus, does not need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

The short version is "no; pick a name that starts with a letter"

If you use a name that starts with a number you'll have to use `"` every time you mention the column name, *and* you'll have to get the case right. Your column is called `"100_title"`, not `"100_Title"` or `"100_TITLE"`

Call it `title_100`, then you can refer to it as any case, even `TiTLe_100` if you like, and generally your life will be easier